# angular2 / typescript class inheritance with generic types

Tags: class, angular, inheritance, typescript, types

Hope one of you **angular2 / typescript wizards** can help out or at least provide a pointer in the right direction, before I got crazy :-)

Here is what I'd like to

- have a **parent class** that implements it's own defined parent Interface, however using **Generic Types** so I can when creating a child class provide it with the child's specific and tailored class & data Interface.
- the child class should be able to **extend** the parent data class by

  - being able to overwrite default/parent set variables
  - overwriting parent functions() and have the child's version called instead of the parent's default

In the below pseudo code example, I would like the call to the child's (inherited) `someOtherfunction()` to return "2"...

Am I asking for too much?
I can't seem to find any decent examples on the web...

How do I get this right?

Thank you -
Oliver

(CODE BELOW MAY BE BROKEN, IT'S JUST FOR ILLUSTRATION)

```
// 
// Parent Class
// 

export interface ICoreData <T> {
    observeItems: Observable <T[]> ;
    items: Array <T>;
}

@Injectable()
export class CoreData<T> implements ICoreData<T> {

    public observeItems: Observable<T[]>;
    private items: Array<T>;

    constructor( 'Dependency Injection...' ) {}

    coreFunction(): number {
        return 1;
    }
    someOtherfunction(){
        return this.coreFunction();
    }
}

// 
// Child class
// 

export interface IMyDataStructure {
    name: string;
    age: string;    
}

export interface ISpecificData extends ICoreData<IMyDataStructure> {
    someExtraKey: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class SpecificData extends CoreData<IMyDataStructure> implements ISpecificData {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    coreFunction(): number{
        // 
        // This function should "overwrite" the parent's original function 
        // and be called by the parent's someOtherfunction() function 
        // 
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what problem do you have with the code above? There's no child class there, btw.

Comment: Why are the `class`es annotated with `@Injectable()`? Is your problem with dependency injection?

Comment: The above doesn't compile; while I gave it my best try, it seems to be the wrong or at least not fully correct approach to what I want to achieve (as per my description).
Re: DI , I haven't even gotten that far to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not asking too much.  However you can't use `interface`s to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.  You need to extend a `class`, which can be generic.

An `interface` is simply a contract, or a blueprint if you like, for a data type.  There is no functionality associated with an `interface`.  However in your case you wanted to be able to have methods on the base class; methods you could override in the derived.

The way I usually do this is to declare an `abstract` base class (so that the base class can't be instantiated itself), and then `extend` classes from that.  Here's an example:

Note, I've removed all the Angular2 cruft in order to keep the example as simple as possible.

```
abstract class Base<T> {
  constructor(public controlled: T) { }

  doIt(): string {
    return `Base.doIt: ${JSON.stringify(this.controlled)}`;
  }

  doSomethingElse(): string {
    return `Base.doSomethingElse: ${JSON.stringify(this.controlled)}`;
  }
};

interface Foo {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

class Derived extends Base<Foo> {
  constructor(foo: Foo) {
    super(foo);
  }

  doSomethingElse(): string {
    return `Derived.doSomethingElse: ${JSON.stringify(this.controlled)}`;
  }
};

let d: Derived = new Derived({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' });

console.log(`doIt ==> ${d.doIt()}`);
console.log(`doSomethingElse ==> ${d.doSomethingElse()}`);
```

Output:

```
doIt ==> Base.doIt: {"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"} 
doSomethingElse ==> Derived.doSomethingElse: {"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20controlled%3A%20T)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20doIt()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%60Base.doIt%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(this.controlled)%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20doSomethingElse()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%60Base.doSomethingElse%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(this.controlled)%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20Base%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(foo%3A%20Foo)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super(foo)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20doSomethingElse()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%60Derived.doSomethingElse%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(this.controlled)%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20d%3A%20Derived%20%3D%20new%20Derived(%7B%20foo%3A%20'foo'%2C%20bar%3A%20'bar'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60doIt%20%3D%3D%3E%20%24%7Bd.doIt()%7D%60)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60doSomethingElse%20%3D%3D%3E%20%24%7Bd.doSomethingElse()%7D%60)%3B).

Comment: Thank you, John.
The Interface part I added bc I thought I needed this to ensure app wide auto-complete / check of class methods and varying data (structures). Which could be different per child.

Ie. in your case it could be **Foo** for one child, and **FooFoo** (with other data attributes for another.

**Base /  child functions:**
You example doesn't touch on the two functions interacting, eg.:
Base:
`doIt(): string {
    return doSomethingElse();
  }`
 - so if `base.doIt()` would call `base.doSomething()` would then `child('base inherited').doIt()` call `child.doSomething()` ?

Comment: Oh, and last one: can I use the above as an Injectable service? Ie. not using with a **new Derived()** approach

Comment: Btw. THANK YOU for the Playground link, that service is worth pure gold.
With your pointers and the option to quickly test...I got it....posted below.

Comment: I was going to post the answer...but can't anymore...lol...who did I offend here??